# rails multiple belongs_to assignments with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, belongs-to

My problem is that how to assign multiple belongs_to associations with nested attributes?

I want to build a issue system. When I create a issue, I also want to create the first comment as the issue body.

So, I have following Models:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable

  validates :title, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true

  validates :content, :user, presence: true
end
```

and I have the IssuesController as follow:

```
class IssuesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! #devise authentication

  def new
    @issue = Issue.new
    @issue.comments.build
  end

  def create
    @issue = Issue.new(issue_params)
    @issue.save
  end

  private

  def issue_params
    params.require(:issue).permit(:title, comments_attributes: [:content])
  end
end
```

and the following is my form (using slim template with simple_form and nested_form gems):

```
= simple_nested_form_for @issue do |f|

  = f.input :title

  = f.fields_for :comments do |cf|
    = cf.input :content

  = f.button :submit
```

In this case, I don't know how to assign `current_user` to the comment created by nested attributes.

Any suggestions or other approaches? Thanks!

Comment: hidden field called :user inside the comments section?

Comment: I have tried this approach, and it works. But I think it is not secure.

Comment: what do you mean as not secure? Fear of the user fiddling with the field? Then do it in the controller. When building the comment, pass the current user as attribute, and check it again on the create.

Comment: do you mean like this: `@issue.comments.each {|c| c.user = current_user}` ?

Comment: pretty much. But that sets each comment to the current user. Not sure if that's your intended behavior.

Comment: I think it is ok if I do this only in create action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, there's two ways of doing this.
The first way is to add a hidden field in your subform to set the current user:

```
= simple_nested_form_for(@issue) do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.fields_for(:comments) do |cf|
    = cf.input(:content)
    = cf.hidden(:user, current_user)
  = f.submit
```

If you do not trust this approach in fear of your users fiddling with the fields in the browser, you can also do this in your controller.

```
class IssuesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! #devise authentication

  def new
    @issue = Issue.new
    @issue.comments.build
  end

  def create
    @issue = Issue.new(issue_params)
    @issue.comments.first.user = current_user
    @issue.save
  end

  private

  def issue_params
    params.require(:issue).permit(:title, comments_attributes: [:content])
  end
end
```

This way you take the first comment that is created through the form and just manually assign the user to it. Then you know for the sure that the first created comment belongs to your current user.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add `user_id` as `current_user.id` when you use params

```
class IssuesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! #devise authentication

  def new
    @issue = Issue.new
    @issue.comments.build
  end

  def create
    @issue = Issue.new(issue_params)
    @issue.save
  end

  private

  def issue_params
    params[:issue][:comment][:user_id] = current_user.id
    params.require(:issue).permit(:title, comments_attributes: [:content, :user_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Dose this means I need to add a 'comment' method or association to Issue Model ?